# multiple times date is alerted

Tags: jquery, onchange

Here when i choose a date,the alert is coming three time where i need only one time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.attendance_date').change(function(){


  alert();
    });    
});
</script>
<div class="col-lg-5">
     <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" required name="attendance_date" id="attendance_date"  class="form-control datepicker attendance_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" data-date-format="<?= config_item('date_picker_format'); ?>" required>
           <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
           </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you replace those `php` with hard coded values, so that we can test it properly? Regardless, I tried it and only one alert shows for me

Comment: are you sure, it alerting multiple times? because i have checked it worked properly.

Comment: Once you changed the `attendance_date` focus of control `change event` raised and `alert` clas

Comment: i don't know why am getting three alerts and you people are getting on alert when a date is choosed

Comment: create a JSFIddle where you are able to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here i got by changing my code like this

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker1').datepicker({
        clearBtn: true,
        todayHighlight: false,
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        todayBtn: "linked",

    }) .on('changeDate', function(e){

      var dt=$("#attendance_date").val();
      //alert(dt);
      var project_id=$("#project_ids").val();
      var url='<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/employee_attendance/ajax_attendance';
      $.post(url, {dt:dt,id:project_id}, function(data)
      { 
       //alert();
       $('#backup').html(data); 
      });

    });
});
```